# How to add the object values into table using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngSanitize"]);
app.controller("controller", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [{
        item: "Shopping",
        status: true
    }, {
        item: "Cleaning",
        status: false
    }];

}]);
```

and html

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller='controller'>
        <table border=1 ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
            <tr>
                <td>{{task.item}}</td>
                <td>{{task.status}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried as above but i could not able to attach header to the table.And at the place of Done I am tring to attach a checkbox...I mean if status is true the chexk box must be checked or else unchecked.

```
Output:
Item       Done
Shopping    checkbox with ticked
Cleaning    checkbox without ticked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [documentation for checkbox input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Not exactly the answer, but why do you repeat table instead of rows?

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller='controller'>
        <table border=1 >
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
                <td>{{task.item}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.status"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I don't see any sense in table in your case.

```
<span ng-repeat="task in tasks">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.status"> {{task.item}}
</span>
```

That would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Do changes as follows in the HTML.

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ListController">
    <table border="1" ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{task.item}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.status">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Do changes in the Angular js as follows.

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [{
        item: "Shopping",
        status: true
    }, {
        item: "Cleaning",
        status: false
    }];
}]);
```